# javascript math with decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, math

I have numbers array:  `[1, 1.241241, 5.2133213]`

here is numbers with dot. I want to split them and stay only like this:  `[1, 1.2, 5.2]`

How can I make this?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: javascript string slice but it doesn't work

Comment: You'd be better off looking into the `toFixed` method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Do you want to split them of just to truncate the digits ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** method.

```js
var data = [1, 1.241241, 5.2133213];

// iterate and generate new array
var res = data.map(function(v) {
  // check fractional part present if present remove 
  // the remaining part using toFixed and convert back to number
  return Math.round(v) == v ? v : Number(v.toFixed(1));
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @NewUbuntuDeveloper : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    if (parseInt(a[i]) != a[i])
        a[i] = Number(a[i].toFixed(1));
}
```

The snippet above (I hope this is what you were looking for) change only numbers that aren't integers - and just return their first digit..

Comment: What's wrong with changing integers? `var x = 5; Number(x.toFixed(1))` is still `5`. JavaScript doesn't differentiate between integer and float types - they are all the same thing. If a number happens to have a fraction part, then it's shown, otherwise it's not. Thus `5.0 === 5` will return `true` because they are both the same thing.

Comment: I know that - but look in the question - he wanted that 1 stay 1 and won't become to 1.0

Comment: It won't become `1.0`. That's exactly what I've said. Seriously just copy and paste this and see what you get `var x = 5; Number(x.toFixed(1))`. Or better yet, just call `console.log(1.0)` and see if you get `1.0` out.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop and toFixed:

```
var x = 0;
var len = my_array.length;
while(x < len){ 
  my_array[x] = my_array[x].toFixed(2); 
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take your input and determine first if it is a float, since you don't want integers to be changed.

```js
cropNum(1);
cropNum(1.241241);
cropNum(5.2133213);

function cropNum(n) {
  if (Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0) {
    return parseFloat(Math.round(n * 100) / 100).toFixed(1)
  }

  return n;
}

// returns:
// 1
// 1.2
// 5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=[1, 1.241241, 5.2133213];
var b=[];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    c = a[i].toFixed(1);
b.push(c);

} console.log(b);
```